# SVGs inside multiple details / summary elements (Inertia, Vue, Tailwind)

Tags: html, vue.js, svg, webpack, inertiajs

I have a vue file with details / summary elements. The content inside the details element contains some SVGs. In the first element everything is working fine, but in the following elements the rendering of the SVGsseemed to be bugged. I can't find any solution, yet someone with this problem.

Behavior of the SVGs:

- Sometimes everything is rendering fine
- Sometimes the SVGs in only one element after the first details / summary element are shown
- Sometimes no SVGs after the first element are shown
- Sometimes after opening the first details / summary element "triggers" the SVGs in the other elements to appear
- Sometimes if I mark random text inside the element makes the SVGs appear

So basically the behavior of the SVGs on every page reload seems to be random for me. I don't know what triggers this, but I never ran into these problem before. Is it because of the summary / details element? Is it an issue with vue? I included my webpack file for laravel mix in case it's related.

The SVGs elements are always there, but invisible. No CSS / tailwind styles or anything applied. All other elements like text etc. are rendered fine. Anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

And of course SVGs have a valid path, just can't share the SVGs. But all of them are working just fine in the first details / summary element.

```js
// webpack.mix.js

const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const path = require("path");

 mix.alias({
     ziggy: path.resolve("vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue"),
 });
 
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
      require('tailwindcss'),
      require('autoprefixer')
    ])
    .sourceMaps(true, 'source-map')
    .alias({
        '@': 'resources/js',
    });

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

```html
// Details.vue

<script setup>
defineProps({
    setup: Object,
})
</script>

<template>


  // The first details / summary element displays svg correctly
  <details class="bg-gray-800 duration-300" id="general">

    <summary class="bg-inherit px-5 py-3 text-lg cursor-pointer text-teal-200">
      GENERAL
    </summary>

    <div class="bg-gray-900 px-5 py-3">

      <div class="grid grid-cols-12 gap-4 text-center justify-items-center">

        <div>
          <svg data-name="Layer 1" class="mt-2" height="75" viewBox="0 0 128 128" width="75"                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><path>.....</path></svg>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </details>


  // Following summary / details elements are "bugged" with svg
  <details class="bg-gray-800 duration-300" id="general">

    <summary class="bg-inherit px-5 py-3 text-lg cursor-pointer text-teal-200">
      2ND ELEMENT
    </summary>

    <div class="bg-gray-900 px-5 py-3">

      <div class="grid grid-cols-12 gap-4 text-center justify-items-center">

        <div>
          <svg data-name="Layer 1" class="mt-2" height="75" viewBox="0 0 128 128" width="75"                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><path>.....</path></svg>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </details>
  
</template>
```

Comment: do you have multiple id attributes with the same value on the page?

Comment: I had it at first but removed all of them already to find out what’s going on. It remains the same wired behavior.

Comment: without a [mcve] I doubt we can help.

Comment: I narrowed the problem down to the vue file as far as I know. I couldn't include the SVG path because they are paid. I tested all SVGs now in the same vue file and they are working fine, as long as they are not included in the details element. 

When I add just one SVG to an details element, only the SVGs in the first details element will be rendered. All other SVGs are not visible anymore then, checked the CSS classes from the invisible SVGs:

img, svg, video, canvas, audio, iframe, embed, object {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

Comment: Maybe I should just get rid of the details / summary element.